# Snap permissions: difference between "home folder" and "personal-files"

Tags: permissions, snap, 21.10

According to the [permission settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8adcC.png) in the Ubuntu software store there is a difference between the two permissions **Access files in your home folder** and **personal-files: allows access to personal files or directories**. Sadly I couldn't find any explanation to what the difference is. Does anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Home folders" allows *read/write* access to all **visible** (not hidden) files and folders in your home directory. So this interface is to gain access to personal user data, i.e. documents and other files in a user defined folder structure under the home folder.

"Personal files or directories" allows access to specified files and folders in your home directory. The developer must declare the list of files/folder where the application should have access. An application may, for example, wish to import an existing configuration. This interface is to gain access to user configuration data in a known location.